# How to map Observable.forkJoin() responses with corresponding requests

Tags: angular

I have a pipe which utilizes the httpClient to give a response observable. I have list of request URLs. So, the code looks like this:

```
let observables = urls.map(url=>myPipe.transform(url));
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(results=>console.log(results));
```

I want to create a Map/Object which will map the request urls to their respective responses. Like:

```
{
   url1 : response1,
   url2 : response2
   ...
}
```

I want them to be available at once, so using forkJoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your pipe transforms url to http request, so

try this:

```
let observables = Object.fromEntries(urls.map(url=>[url, myPipe.transform(url)]));
forkJoin(observables).subscribe(results=>console.log(results));
```

at first we create an object `{url: Observable}`, and then with `forkJoin` we can do exactly what you asked

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it gives me array of arrays.

Comment: did you forget to add `Object.fromEntries`?

Comment: (<any>Object).entries() as Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor

Comment: Thanks for the cozy solution. Added `fromEntries = arr => Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(arr, ([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}) ));` as I didn't have support for the `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: how come you don't have it? are you using very old version of typescript?